# SQL Function Replacing 0 with Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions

Hi on the contrary to what I found on the internet, I need to replace a 0 with a null so that in the table i will have a null instead of a 0.

Currently I did the following:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION retunNull(@num nvarchar(255))
RETURNS nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@num IS '0')
        BEGIN
        @num = NULL
        END
        RETURN @num
END
GO
```

this is giving me the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure retunNull, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near '0'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure retunNull, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Can anyone help me and guide me to the right direction?
PS This must be done in a function since it will be used several times

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing a `SET` statement. `SET @num = NULL` and the test should be `IF(@num = '0')`

Can't you just use the built in `NULLIF` function instead of creating a scalar UDF?

Comment: 10x, didn't know about nullif, looked it up and makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT NULLIF(MyColumn, 0)
FROM MyTable
```